# Subtract two columns with text and numbers in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have two columns that contain information in the following format.

```
Column A - 35 days
Column B - 29 days
```

How can i subtract the two columns to show just a number, like 35 days - 29 days = 6.

Answer (score 1):

The following equation should do the trick

```
= VALUE(MID(A1, 1, FIND(" ",A1))) - VALUE(MID(B1, 1,FIND(" ",B1)))
```

First we find the index of the space " " in the cell using `FIND(" ", A1)`. Then we cut the string in the cell and we take the first index to the index of the space by `MID(A1, 1, ...)`. Then we convert this value to a number using `VALUE(...)`.

If all your days always have 2 digits, none of them are >= 100, then we can simplify this by

```
= VALUE(MID(A1, 1, 2)) - VALUE(MID(B1, 1,2))
```

But, I think the general case is preferable.

Answer (score 1):

Change the cell number format to Custom with a format mask of `0 \d\a\y\s`. Now type in *35* into A1 and *29* into B1. Now, while the cells display *35 days* and *29 days* they can be conventionally used like,

```
'on the worksheet
=a1-b1
'in vba
i = range("a1").value - range("b1").value
'in vba to see *35 days* in the Immediate window
?range("a1").text
```

You could even get a little fancier with a custom number format of,

```
[>1]0 \d\a\y\s;[=1]0 \d\a\y;0 \d\a\y\s;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Replace` function and replace days with an empty string, then you can convert your string to a integer with `CInt`:

```
?CInt(Replace("39 days", "days", ""))-CInt(Replace("25 days", "days", ""))
  14
```

Edit:
or like Jeeped suggested in the commment you could use:

```
?Val("39 days")-Val("25 days")
  14
```

Comment: fwiw, VBA's Val command will discard the text suffix; e.g. `?val("35 days")` returns 35 as a number. This differentiates the Val command from the worksheet's VALUE function which does not provide this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `SUBSTITUTE()` function.

```
=(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"days",""))*1)-TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(B1,"days",""))*1
```

[image]

***Edit:***
Only `SUBSTITUTE()` will also work.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"days","")-SUBSTITUTE(B1,"days","")
```

Comment: That be shortened to `=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"days","")-SUBSTITUTE(B1,"days","")`

Comment: Yes. But I use `TRIM()` if there any extra space.

Comment: You can put as many spaces as you want between *35* and *days*. The trim and *1 is still not necesaary since the maths subtraction is really what performs the text-to-number conversion.

Comment: Oh! that interesting. I do not tried that. `=(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"days",""))-SUBSTITUTE(B1,"days","")` this is working fine. Thanks @Jeeped

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Sub SumDays()
Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long, cellA As String, cellB As String
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To lastRow
    cellA = Cells(i, 1).Value
    cellB = Cells(i, 2).Value
    Cells(i, 3).Value = CInt(Mid(cellA, 1, InStr(1, cellA, " ") - 1)) + CInt(Mid(cellB, 1, InStr(1, cellB, " ") - 1))
Next
End Sub
```